# Can I compile Flatpak from source?

Tags: flatpak

I recently downloaded a Flatpak Epiphany package. However, there is no support on my distro for Flatpak. So is there a way to compile it from source?

Comment: I realize it was down voted, but if someone does not tell me what is wrong, it's quite useless, since I have no idea of what is wrong with it. Besides I want to do a similar topic for a similar package system (the one Ubuntu uses) and would be very benefice if someone explained it to me, as to allow me to do commit such mistake once more.

Comment: What did you try, what kind of errors you see, what kind of commands you exec?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov. I downloaded the flatpak epiphany package from somewhere to see what is it. I opened it and saw that I had no idea of what to do with the flatpak file of the package. I started to look around on its website for the code but could not find it. Stephen Kitt pointed it for me and that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[The main Flatpak site](https://flatpak.org/) doesn’t make this easy to find, but the Flatpak source code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/) and is built in a manner familiar to most Autotools-based projects:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak.git
cd flatpak
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You’ll need a number of dependencies, which are detailed in [the `README.md` file](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/blob/master/README.md). You’ll also probably need to adjust some of the `./configure` flags depending on your target environment.

You may also prefer to work from [a release tarball](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/releases) instead of cloning the repository.